# prove that $\log_2(n+1)-\log_3(2n+1) \le c$ eventually

Tags: inequality, logarithms, asymptotics

How can I prove that there is $c>0$ such that starting from a specific $n$ the following is true:
$$
\log_2(n+1) - \log_3(2n+1) \le c
$$

Comment: The main problem I want to solve is to know if this is true or false, I drew the function and it "seems" to be true but wasn't able to prove it

Comment: Welcome to the website, I advise you to update your question to reflect the original one as you are not certain that the statement you are asking to prove is actually correct.

Comment: I need to post an image can you give me 10 points for a sec?

Comment: I don't think it's warranted to cross-post such a simple question on several stack exchanges: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65324498/is-log-2n1-log-32n1-o1/65324934?noredirect=1#comment115488257_65324934

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**
$$
\log_2(n+1) -\log_3(2n+1) \le \log_2(n+1)
$$
so suffices to prove that $\log_2(n+1) \le cn$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}^+$, which is equivalent to proving
$$
n+1 = 2^{\log_2(n+1)} \le 2^{cn} = \left(2^c\right)^n = k^n
$$
for $k=2^c \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Can you finish?

---

**UPDATE**

Now that you updated the question, it became a more interesting problem. One way is to consider the function
$$
f(x)
 = \log_2(x+1) - \log_3(2x+1)
 = \frac{\ln(x+1)}{\ln 2} - \frac{\ln(2x+1)}{\ln 3}
$$
over $x \ge 0$ and prove that the function is bounded by showing that it achieves a maximum or reaches a horizontal asymptote.

Achieving maximum (if true) can be shown by solving $f'(x)=0$ and computing $f''(x)$ to establish concavity with the 2nd derivative test.

Horizontal asymptotes are also part of standard calculus class.

Can you finish?

---

**UPDATE 2**

It appears this claim is not true. Note that as $x \to \infty$, we have
$$
\begin{split}
f(x)
 &\approx \log_2(x) - \log_3(2x) \\
 &= \log_2(x) - \log_3(x) - \log_3 2 \\
 &= \frac{\ln x}{\ln 2} - \frac{\ln x}{\ln 3} - \log_3 2 \\
 &= \ln x \left(\frac{1}{\ln 2} - \frac{1}{\ln 3}\right) - \log_3 2 \\
 &= a\ln(x) - b,
\end{split}
$$
where $a = \frac{1}{\ln 2} - \frac{1}{\ln 3} > 0$, so $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. That means the difference between your logarithmic factors diverges with increasing $n$...

Comment: But that's in case it's true right, if it's false then this won't work

Comment: @MrCalc it is, indeed, true for any $k>1$ and all $n$ large enough

Comment: but someone mentioned the claim is false and deleted his comment

Comment: @MrCalc exactly - he made a mistake :) perhaps misread your original question, happens to the best of us sometimes

Comment: updated my question, it's c*1 and not c*n sorry

Comment: @MrCalc please see the update

Comment: @MrCalc please see another update - you may need to look for asymptotes as $x\to \infty$

Comment: @MrCalc and yet another update - your claim is NOT true

Answer (score 0):

$\log_2(n+1)-\log_3(2n+1)=\dfrac{\log_3(n+1)}{\log_32}-\log_3(2n+1)=$

$=\log_23\cdot\log_3(n+1)-\log_3(2n+1)=$

$=\left[\log_2\left(\dfrac32\right)+1\right]\cdot\log_3(n+1)-\log_3(2n+1)=$

$=\log_2\left(\dfrac32\right)\cdot\log_3(n+1)+\log_3(n+1)-\log_3(2n+1)=$

$=\log_2\left(\dfrac32\right)\cdot\log_3(n+1)+\log_3\left(\dfrac{n+1}{2n+1}\right)>$

$>\log_2\left(\dfrac32\right)\cdot\log_3(n+1)+\log_3\left(\dfrac12\right)\to+\infty$

as $\;n\to+\infty\;.$

Hence, there does not exist any $\;c>0\;$ such that

$\log_2(n+1)-\log_3(2n+1)\le c\;$ eventually.